# How to modify the default value for a GenMap in Scala?

Tags: scala

The generic GenMap does not have withDefaultValue and I am not sure how to modify the default directly. Is there a way to do this?

Edit: The function I need it for looks like this:

```
  def declassify(dots: GenSeq[Dot], locations: GenSeq[Dot]): GenMap[Dot, GenSeq[Dot]] = {
      dots.groupBy {case dot => findFurthest(dot,locations)}
  }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`GenMap` is a trait that does not define a way to have/use a default value.

If you you instanciate a GenMap yourself, just use `HashMap` then you will have `withDefaultValue`.

Or you can use

```
  genMap.get(key).getOrElse(default)
```

to get the same behaviour.

### Edit

```
def declassify(dots: GenSeq[Any], locations: GenSeq[Any]): HashMap[Any, GenSeq[Any]] = {
    HashMap(dots.groupBy { case dot => "Furtherest" }.toSeq.seq:_*)
  }
```

You can use this and add the default value inside or outside of the method or the following to add it inside.

```
def declassify(dots: GenSeq[Any], locations: GenSeq[Any]): Map[Any, GenSeq[Any]] = {
    HashMap.empty[Any, GenSeq[Any]].withDefaultValue(Seq("default")) ++ dots.groupBy { case dot => "Furtherest" }
  }
```

Scala often crates a `HashMap` internal. This will avoid create a new HashMap yourself in this case

```
  def declassify(dots: GenSeq[String], locations: GenSeq[String]): Map[String, GenSeq[String]] = {
    val x = dots.groupBy { case dot => "Furtherest" }
    val z = x match {
      case y: HashMap[String, GenSeq[String]] => y
      case y => HashMap(x.toSeq.seq: _*)
    }

    z withDefaultValue Seq("default")
  }
```

Comment: I am aware of the above, but this is kind of an assignment, so I need to either add empty elements to a list which would slow down the function 10x or find a way to hack default somehow.

Comment: why do you need to return a `GenMap`at all?

Comment: It can be either a concurrent or a sequential map. `GenMap` is a supertype of both.

Comment: Both methods can be defined with `GenMap` as return type.

Comment: I am not too familiar with Scala, but I do not want to use a hash based map specifically just for this function. Functional maps can be tree based as well. Also you examples look like they would extra work each time the types are converted, which I'd like to avoid. Actually, at this point I need to ask what sort of map is created when I use `groupBy` on `GenSeq`? `HashMap`? I should also note that I already did pass the assignment, so this is just for my own curiosity now.

Comment: Also, what does `seq:_*` do? Is this a cast?

Comment: `seq:_*` converts a seq to var args

Comment: What kind of `Map` `groupBy` creates depends on the specific type of seq for the method input. But you can expect it to be a hash map. if you want to avoid instance creation in this case, I'll give you an optimazition

Answer (score 1):

I've had a similar problem and I worked around it like this (transferred to your question):

```
val DEFAULT = ???

def declassify(dots: GenSeq[Dot], locations: GenSeq[Dot]): GenMap[Dot, GenSeq[Dot]] = {
  val m = dots.groupBy { case dot => findFurthest(dot,locations) }
  m ++ locations.filterNot(m.keySet.contains)
                .map((_, DEFAULT))
                .toMap
}
```

I have to admit that this does not look extremely elegant, but it solves the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Another option is to map your locations to a tuple with a default, then convert to a map, something like:

```
val DEFAULT = ???
def declassify(dots: GenSeq[Dot], locations: GenSeq[Dot]): GenMap[Dot, GenSeq[Dot]] = {
  val m = dots.groupBy { case dot => findFurthest(dot,locations) }
  locations.map(location => (location, m.getOrElse(location, DEFAULT)).toMap
}
```